# Rails database migration fails with “duplicate column name: email”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am fairly new to Rails and I'm currently installing the devise gem.

When I created a User model and attempted to migrate the database:

```
$ rails generate devise User
$ rake db:migrate
```

I get the following error response:

```
== 20160717064710 AddDeviseToUsers: migrating =================================
-- change_table(:users)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm not exactly sure what a schema is for, but here is a copy of my schema. It's empty, and I thought it was suppose to be until the database is migrated:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 0) do

end
```

And here is a copy of my migration file in db/migrate:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string  

 :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

          ## Lockable
          # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
          # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
          # t.datetime :locked_at


          t.timestamps null: false
        end

        add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
        add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
        # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
        # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
      end
    end
```

I'm fairly new to Rails, so I'm actually quite lost on what this error means. I'm assuming I apparently already have a column named: "email".

Also, I commented out the t.string :email and typed the following:

```
rails db:rollback
rails db:migrate
```

And I get a differnet error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Key column 'email' doesn't exist in table: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_email`  ON `users` (`email`)
```

Answer (score 4):

In the migration file generated by Devise, change the line

`t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""`

to:

`t.change :email, :string,     null: false, default: ""`

Instead of trying to create a new email colum, the migration changes the existing one to the specifications of Devise

Then run rake db:migrate

Comment: undefined method `change' for #<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::MySQL::TableDefinition:0x0000000489f748>

Comment: update the syntax? What do you mean? (Sorry, I'm new)

Comment: I updated the code in my answer. Run rake db:rollback, then change the migration file's line for the email, to the second code line in my answer

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Table 'users' already exists: CREATE TABLE `users` (`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `string` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `encrypted_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, `reset_password_token` varchar(255), `reset_password_sent_at` datetime, `remember_created_at` datetime, `sign_in_count` int DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL, `current_sign_in_at` datetime, `last_sign_in_at` datetime, `current_sign_in_ip` varchar(255), `last_sign_in_ip` varchar(255), `created_at` datetime NOT NULL, `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: If your just starting your app, probably best to drop the whole table all together and restart. do that by running `rake db:drop`
`rake db:create`
`rake db:migrate` Do that in the order written

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate column name 'email': ALTER TABLE `users` ADD `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL

Comment: If you still have the devise migration, just comment out the line where it adds the email column by putting a `#` infront of the line. Then run rake db:migrate again so it doesnt add the email column

Comment: Mysql2::Error: Key column 'email' doesn't exist in table: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `index_users_on_email`  ON `users` (`email`)

Comment: I just started my project today. Should I restart and completely install devise first?

Comment: Restarting would probably be easier, although in projects later down the track I wouldn't recommend it. The problem is that you already have created a table named Users, is this correct? When you make an app and are installing devise for users, dont make a table called Users and the problem won't occur

Comment: Also, If you have any code you want to keep from the project like some css or something, make sure to copy it somewhere!

Comment: I didn't know I made a table named users. I'll follow instructions better next time. Thanks for ur help!

Answer (score 1):

@GVS try this: you've edited your migration file inadvertantly. This looks like where your problem is.

**1. Find this line in your migration file and comment it out or delete it**

```
 :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

You've obviously changed it. That's what's causing your problems. It should be a few lines above.

**2. do a migration roll back as you have done.**

**3. leave the email column in there and rerun the migration.**

It should now work. (but if you plan on leaving the email out then you have to remove the "add_index :users, :email,                unique: true" line at the bottom of the migration as well. also look to your users model and make the appropriate changes there as well.)

I hope this helps. if it still doesn't work post back your errors and I will modify my answer.

good luck!

rgds

BKSpurgeon